# Change of basis for transformation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

The linear transformation $S : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by the standard matrix $A_\epsilon = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} $. Find the matrix for S in the basis $ F = \{ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \}$

How do you get the answer $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Do you know how to find the matrix for a given linear operator under a given basis?

Comment: @user771918 I know how to find the "change of basis" matrix, allowing me to go from $\epsilon$ to F, that matrix would be $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\ \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$, where the columns are the standard basis vectors with respect to basis F. Is that what you meant?

Comment: It wasn't what I meant, but that'll do nicely. Let's call this matrix $Q$. Then $Q^{-1}$ is the change of basis matrix from $F$ to $\epsilon$. You should be able to compute the matrix you need by computing $QA_\epsilon Q^{-1}$.

Comment: You might also care to notice that $F$ is a basis of eigenvectors. You might have a theorem connecting such bases to diagonal matrices...

Comment: @user771918 I see how $QA_\epsilon {Q}^{-1}$ becomes $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, which is also the matrix containing the eigenvalues 3 and 0 on the diagonal. However I fail to see why this is the sought matrix for S in the basis F.

Comment: @user771918  I am aware of the general formula $D ={P}^{-1}AP$, where D contains the eigenvalues on the diagonal (rest are zeroes) and P contains A's eigenvectors in the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that, relative to an arbitrary ordered basis, the coordinates of the basis vectors themselves are our old friends $(1,0,0,0,\dots)^T$, $(0,1,0,0,\dots)^T$, $(0,0,1,0,\dots)^T$ and so on. Recall also that the columns of a transformation matrix are just the images of the basis vectors *expressed relative to that basis*. So, you just need to work out what the coordinates of those images are. I’ll do the first one for you: $S(1,1)^T = (3,3)^T = 3(1,1)^T+0(-2,1)^T$,  so the first column is $(3,0)^T$. The second column is even simpler.

Comment: Thanks, I'm close to getting it, I see that 3 and 0 make up the first column of the sought matrix. However, I don't see the rationale for $(3,3)^T = 3(1,1)^T + 0(-2,1)^T.$ What's the reasoning for that? I can see that $(1,1)^T$ and $(-2,1)^T$ is the new basis, but why are we using it in this way?

Comment: @eriksan Do you remember the definition of the coordinates of a vector?

Comment: Thanks, while I don't remember the definition verbatim, I assume you mean that the coordinates of a vector are given with respect to some basis (such as the standard basis). So what we did above was writing $(3,0)^{T}$ with respect to the desired basis F, am I right?

Comment: @eriksan That’s right. The coordinates of a vector are just the coefficients of the unique linear combination of basis vectors that produces the vector. I made that linear combination explicit by including the $0(-2,1)^T$ term.

Answer (score 2):

Let ${\rm std}$ be the standard basis and $\mathcal{F}$ be the new basis you have. One has $$[S]_{\mathcal{F}} = [{\rm Id}]_{{\rm std},\mathcal{F}}[S]_{\rm std}[{\rm Id}]_{\mathcal{F}, {\rm std}}.$$What is $[{\rm Id}]_{\mathcal{F}, {\rm std}}$? Evaluate ${\rm Id}$ in the elements of $\mathcal{F}$, write the results as combinations of elements in ${\rm std}$ and place the coefficients in columns. In this case it just amounts to putting the elements of $\mathcal{F}$ themselves in columns. So $$[S]_{\mathcal{F}} = \begin{pmatrix} 1& -2 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1& -2 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$